# cannot create directory using mkdir() method

Tags: java, mkdir

```
import java.io.*;
public class mkdir 
{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        mkdir m = new mkdir();

        File d = new File("D:\\Mobile Developer tools\\eclipse");
        try 
        {
            if(d.mkdir())
                System.out.println("Directory created :D");
            else 
                System.out.println("Directory is not created :(");  

        } catch(Exception e) {

        }

    }


}
```

I tried the above code to create a directory but the above code shows the output "Directory is not created :(" is there any logical error in this program , thanks in advance

Comment: Check if you have permission to do so.

Comment: did u checked the physical directory? apart from security permission, the mkdir() will return false if the directory already exist. plz check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir()

Comment: You don't have to create an instance of `mkdir` if you use only static methods.

Comment: add this line below ur else block; "System.out.println("Directory exist: " + d.exists());"

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't have `Mobile Developer Tools/` directory on disk `D:`
try

```
d.mkdirs();
```

It will create directories recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
File dir = new File(<directory path>);
if (dir.exists()) {
    System.out.println("Already exist:" + path);
} else {
    dir.mkdir();
    System.out.println("Directory created :" + path);
}
```